# pgrep program with hyphen in linux?

Tags: grep

how to pgrep a program contains hyphen? Considering case like bellow.

c source file name, `program-contains-hypen.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

then keep editing it with `vim`, and run the compiled `program-contains-hypen` in another terminal.

at this time, if I use `pgrep program-contains-hypen`, nothing got; if I use `pgrep -f program-contains-hypen`, two results got.

how to exactly get the pid of program `program-contains-hypen`?

ps:

```
$ pgrep --version
pgrep from procps-ng 3.3.10
```

update:

It's not the problem of hyphen but the length of command line.

see https://askubuntu.com/questions/361104/pgrep-pattern-length-limit.

thanks to @user5631389

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question. pgrep -f is the correct way to do this. If you're getting two results, you have two running processes with that name. You can use pgrep -fa to see the whole command line. For example:

Without -f, you will only be able to use a certain number of characters according to https://askubuntu.com/questions/361104/pgrep-pattern-length-limit. For example:

```
$ pgrep unity-scope-loader 
$ pgrep unity-scope-loade
$ pgrep unity-scope-load
$ pgrep unity-scope-loa
9489
$ pgrep -f unity-scope-loader 
9489
$ pgrep -fa unity-scope-loader
9489 /usr/bin/unity-scope-loader applications/applications.scope applications/scopes.scope commands.scope
$ awk '$11~/unity-scope-loader/{print $2}' <(ps aux)
9489
```

Comment: two running processes: `./program-contains-hyphen` and `vim program-contains-hyphen.c`; Seems that not the problem of hyphen but the length of command line?

Comment: And `cat /proc/xxx/comm` I got `program-contain`, which is exactly 15 characters. same as the 1234567890123456 problem.

Comment: Yep, that's correct. pgrep without the -f option looks up processes in a manner that truncates the name of the file at 15 characters. I don't believe this has anything to do with having hyphens in your process name.

Comment: Thanks, and I am trying to use `alias pgrep='busybox pgrep'` on my embed linux as the `busybox` knows what I want, and `busybox` is always there. I don't want to check which `pgrep` is in using(`busybox` or `procps-ng`).